# Xcode 6 Autolayout with Size Classes - Best practice to bring in off screen UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, xcode6, size-classes

In my app I have part of a UIView that initially takes up a 320 x 115 pt space. After some information is entered by the user that space shrinks in half to the left side and a new UIView is displayed to the right of the initial view, each UIView now taking up half the width of the screen. In the storyboard layout, I just positioned the second view off-screen and moved it on-screen in code.

Now that I am attempting to constrain my views on screen using Autolayout and size classes, I am not sure how to layout the off-screen view in a generic 600 x 600 container without getting serious Autolayout errors.

If anyone could offer advice or direction towards documentation that may be helpful, I would much appreciate it. I can provide any new information, if required.

Regards.

Comment: What I do in that situation is put in on screen with the proper constraints where it will be after the animation completes, then in viewDidLoad of your controller simply set the constraint to move it off screen then proceed with your animation. No need to position it off screen in your storyboard.

Comment: Yes, this ^^^^^^ is correct.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have tried this and I like the idea. Now I just need to get programming constraints in order. Getting there....

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be adding this view when it needed, some kind of lazy initialization :). So when your action trigger situation in which you should show your new view, you've to add it programmatically and manually (in the code) add constraints you need for it. This approach will be the best from the performance point.